# Automation using a batch file to call other .bat files (and provide a decent log)

Tags: batch-file

I am a super beginner in coding, I have never done any programming. However I an using a CFD software called phoenics-VR, we need to run multiple simulation one after another. The software provide a very botched batch codes to do the job. (link: http://www.cham.co.uk/phoenics/d_polis/d_enc/enc_m.htm#mulrun)
Their script requires 2 .bat files and it is not very user friendly (the files has to be in a particular order and name). So I have decided to build a UI and a logging system for my own use.

So far i have the most success using "forfiles" to call the two built-in functions that run the software (runsat & runear).

```
set _1=!date:~0,2!!date:~3,3!!date:~7,2!
set /a "_2=!time:~0,2!!time:~3,2!"

set "filename=log_%_1%_%_2%"
set "log=>>%CD%\%filename%.txt"

echo %username% !date! !time! %log%
echo Working location: %cd% %log%

echo Files found: %log%
FORFILES /S /M *.q1 /C "cmd /c echo @path %log%"

set "_a1=Start of"
set "_a2=Completed"

call C:\phoenics\d_utils\phoepath.bat
FORFILES /S /M *.q1 /C ^"cmd /c copy @path q1 ^&^
echo %_a1% @path !date! !time! %log% ^&^
call runsat f ^&^
call runear ^&^
echo %_a2% @path !date! !time! %log% ^&^
echo : %log% ^"

rem all simulations are finished
    echo ** All Completed ** %log%

:end
```

However the time stamp came back as the time I have first open the batch file. which makes the log useless. And "call runsat f" does not seem to run but got echo in the log.txt

Comment: The timestamp will be the date/time when the script was executed purely because that is what you are asking the batch-file to do. Then what's the deal with all the escaped ampersands? Are you trying to actually chain all those commands? Preferbly call a batchfile with its full name and extension. Finally, though you do not have spaces in your paths, it is best to enclose the path in double quotes. `call "C:\phoenics\d_utils\phoepath.bat"`

Comment: I also see you are using delayedexpansion variables `!date! !time!`. Did you actually `setlocal` `enabledelayedexpansion` earlier in the script which you did not post here?

Comment: yes, i did, setlocal enabledelayedexpansion.